# Why can't we declare uninitialized variables in .bss section using `?` in arbitrary order?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

This code works as intended:

```
section .bss
    var2:      DB     ?     
    X:         DW     ?     ; works
```

With the reservations in opposite order, the code doesn't assemble:

```
section .bss
    X:         DW     ?     
    var2:      DB     ?    ; error with lines in other order
```

I got this error, even though I don't use this label, `var2` on another part of the program (in fact, this is reproducible assembling *just* that code block as a 3-line file).

```
error: label `var2' changed during code generation [-w+error=label-redef-late]
```

I think the `var2` variable is overwritten by the `X` variable because it's a word, on 2 bytes.

I am using NASM, version 2.15.04 to assemble this code (also reproducible with 2.15.05).

Comment: That documentation is for the 2.11 version of NASM.
You can see that from [2.15](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.1) the `?` syntax is supported. 

```
Starting in NASM 2.15, the following MASM–like features have been implemented:

A ? argument to declare uninitialized storage
```

Comment: Perhaps a bug in NASM?

Comment: Out of curiosity, does this work if you substitute `resb 1` and `resw 1` for the `db/dw ?`?

Comment: @Arkku Yes, with `resb` and `resw` it's working.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I am using NASM for 32 bits with `nasm -f elf32 -g`. Let me try your command line.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSMce.png
The only difference it's that I am using Ubuntu 20.04 right now.

Comment: The code in your screenshot is different. Please post the *exact same* code that generates the error, including comments and whitespace.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I update the code from the initial description, it seems that I put the good option by mistake. You can try with that one because it's not working for me. The idea is to have a bigger variable like `X          DW ?` declared before a smaller variable like `var2       DB ? `. Thanks for getting involved in this. I also put the code [here](http://dontpad.com/nasm_bug_?) if it's easier for you.

Comment: Ok, can reproduce the error now with the updated code with both 2.15.04 and .05 sorry about the confusion. And yeah... looks like a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: [my patch was merged](https://github.com/netwide-assembler/nasm/commit/d167b3d4f3dd011bd3e8995ee5f38aa5d646b5ee) and the issue should no longer be present from NASM 2.15.06.

---

After some debugging and poking around in the [source code](https://github.com/netwide-assembler/nasm/) I can confirm my initial suspicion that this is a bug.

The size calculation for instructions of the form `Dx ?` (i.e. any `Dx` which includes a uninitialized storage token `?`) where `Dx` is larger than `DB` internally returns the wrong size (assuming elements of 1 byte instead of the appropriate element size). This has the side effect of inconsistently altering the segment offset of any label following the instruction, causing a mismatch in the final code generation stage which is caught by a couple of checks and makes NASM error out.

Normally I would've simply reported the bug, but since NASM's GitHub repo does not have an "Issues" page active and their Bugzilla currently disallows registration I went ahead and submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/netwide-assembler/nasm/pull/19). The fix seems quite simple, unless there's something that I'm missing, in which case we'll find out (hopefully) soon.

Comment: Nice catch with that! I will make a blog post about this bug, I hope you don't mind mentioning you there for this contribution.

Comment: @MocanuGabriel sure go ahead, glad I could help. If you need a link you can use any of the ones that are on my profile (so/twitter/website).